# $¬\exists_x(P(x) \land Q(x))$ vs. $¬\exists_x(P(x)) \land Q(x)$

Tags: logic, notation, first-order-logic

Are the following two formulas in first order logic equivalent?

$$¬\exists_x(P(x) \land Q(x)) \tag{1}$$

$$¬\exists_x(P(x)) \land Q(x) \tag{2}$$

Would the difference mean something like:

$$'\text{There is no P that is Q}'\tag{1}$$

$$\text{vs.}$$

$$'\text{There is no P, and that non-P is Q}'\tag{2}$$

A reference to a textbook would also be appreciated.

Comment: The second formula has a free variable, and so is not a closed sentence at all.

Comment: Ah yes of course. Silly me... thanks.

Comment: Try with "x is Even" for Px and "x is Odd" for Qx. The first formula is True while the second is False.

Comment: Thanks to everyone who responded! Sorry the question was a bit daft. I’m not a mathematician, and logic notation sometimes confuses me... Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first translation you did is correct, sencond is not.
And Yes, $(1)(2)$ are not equivalent.
\begin{align}
'\text{There is no P that is Q}'
\equiv&\forall_x(P(x)\to\neg Q(x))\tag*{$\color{green}{\boxed{\unicode{x2714}}}$}\\
\equiv&\forall_x(\neg P(x)\lor\neg Q(x))\\
\equiv&\neg\exists_x (P(x) \land Q(x))\tag{1}\\\\
'\text{There is no P, and that non-P is Q}'\equiv&\forall_x(\neg P(x))\land\forall_x(\neg P(x)\to Q(x))\tag*{$\color{red}{\boxed{\unicode{x2718}}}$}\\
\equiv&\boxed{\forall_x(\neg P(x)\land Q(x))}\\
\not\equiv& \neg\exists_x(P(x)) \land Q(x)\tag{2}\\
\\
\text{Note two x are not in Scope of same quantifier}~~~~&\\
\text{To avoid confusing, we denote second x as y}~~~~\\
'\text{There is no P, and that y is Q}'\equiv&\boxed{\forall_x(\neg P(x))\land Q(y)}\tag*{$\color{green}{\boxed{\unicode{x2714}}}$}\\
\equiv&\neg\exists_x(P(x)) \land Q(y)\\
\equiv& \neg\exists_x(P(x)) \land Q(y)\tag{2}
\end{align}

The boxed part is where you got confused, variables with same name in different [Scopes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_(logic)) are not guaranteed to be the same. In this case, second $x$ is not in any  Scope, certainly not same as the first $x$.

Comment: One should write $\forall x$, $\exists x$ instead of $\forall_x$, $\exists_x$.

Comment: @OlivierRoche this is an alternative notation $\dots$ I did see people use both.